# What's the difference between UIWebView and WKWebView when loading local resources

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

I want to load local resources with webView. I built a demo with both UIWebView and WKWebView to do some test with the code below.

```
    let uiWebView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    self.view.addSubview(uiWebView)

    let wkWebView = WKWebView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 400, width: 500, height: 500))
    self.view.addSubview(wkWebView)

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"1", ofType: "png")

    guard let realPath = path else {
        return
    }

    let url = URL(string: realPath)
    let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: realPath)

    if let realUrl = url {
        uiWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url:realUrl))
        wkWebView.load(URLRequest(url:realUrl))
    }


  // uiWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url:fileUrl))
  // wkWebView.load(URLRequest(url:fileUrl))
```

The uiWebView can load the resource but wkWebView can not. But if I use

```
  uiWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url:fileUrl))
  wkWebView.load(URLRequest(url:fileUrl))
```

both uiWebView and wkWebView can work well.
I am confused and can anyone explain that for me:
Shouldn't I use URL(string: realPath) for a local resource? But why UIWebView can use it ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A couple points:

1. Apple [recommends](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview) that you use `WKWebview` for iOS 8 and later. I would avoid writing new code with `UIWebView`.

> In apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the `WKWebView` class instead of using `UIWebView`. Additionally, consider setting the `WKPreferences` property `javaScriptEnabled` to `false` if you render files that are not supposed to run JavaScript.

2. Apple has been trying to move away from *path* and instead wants to use *URI* even for local files. They recommend that you NOT use `/path/to/file.png` and use `file:///path/to/file.png` instead.

As to why one URL works and the other does not, let's make a minimal example:

```
let realPath = "/path/to/file.png"
let url = URL(string: realPath)               // /path/to/file.png
let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: realPath)  // file:///path/to/file.png
```

- `url` does not provide the scheme (a.k.a protocol). It should only be used in conjunction with another URL to give the absolute address of the resource you are trying to reach. `UIWebView` supports it for backwards-compatibility reasons but Apple decided to start clean with `WKWebView`.
- `fileURL` has a scheme (`file://`) that tells the resource is located on the local file system. Other common schemes are `http`, `https`, `ftp`, etc. It's a complete address to a resource so both views know how to resolve it.

Comment: Where does it say UIWebView is deprecated?

Comment: It does not say "deprecated", just "use the WKWebView class instead of using UIWebView". And source code has not been marked as deprecated or with a warning. They don't give more details, so it is not clear to me.

Comment: there's nothing mention on `UIWebView` class reference till date but Just now I saw in Xcode 9 beta 6 that at the place where all UI component listing on storyboard editor, `UIWebView` deprecated.

Comment: The challenge here is that data detectors in WKWebView appear to only support iOS 10+, which is a issue for our user base.  Anyone have a way to stick with WKWebView and detect links in iOS 9?

Comment: UIWebView is marked as deprecated as of iOS 12: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview

Comment: To clarify the timeline in the above comments: At the time of jjxtra's post, there was a note at the top of the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview) instructing developers not to use it UIWebView for iOS8+ apps.  This doesn't constitute explicit deprecation, though I recommend treating such notes as deprecation for purposes of developer decision-making; it's still an official recommendation. On the other hand, now it has been explicitly marked deprecated.

Comment: ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of new apps that use UIWebView APIs starting from April 2020. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information.
After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to App Store Connect.

Answer (score 3):

This might be for security reasons, or just how the `WKWebView` API was implemented.

`WKWebView` has a specific instance method for loading local resources called `loadFileURL(_:allowingReadAccessTo:)`. This was introduced in iOS 9.

### Note

If you are targeting iOS 8.0 or newer, you should be using `WKWebView` instead of `UIWebView`. See: https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview