# Cordova: WKWebView vs. UIWebView in iOS 10

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview

In our Cordova application we have some css issues - e.g. regarding handling of flex box - which occur in iOS 10 but not in iOS 11.

I tried now to include the ionic-wkweb-view in our project. The WKWebview is - according to the logging and after a check in the window element^1 - used and everything works as before.

However, I still see the same rendering issues as before under iOS 10. I wonder now what kind of improvements I can expect in terms of better css support and rendering. I was somehow expecting that the application will now more or less behave the same under iOS 10 and iOS 11.

Is it expected that iOS 10 still is not handling css (e.g. flex box) the same way as iOS 11 when I switch to WKWebview or might there be an issue with the configuration and - despite all evidence - the app is not really running in WKWebView?

^1 [Detect if page is loaded inside WKWebView in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28795476/detect-if-page-is-loaded-inside-wkwebview-in-javascript)

Comment: what is the safari version in the iOS 10 you tested?

Comment: It is iOS 10.3.3

Comment: isn't it the iOS version? Would need the Safari version for support (i read `flex` seems to be supported since Safari 9, with possible support for older versions up to 6.1 with `-webkit` prefix)

Comment: Safari 10 (iPhone 5). However, my question is not about browser support regarding Flexbox, which was just an example for different behavior in iOS 10 and 11. It is a question about what the WKWebView is actually doing and if I should be able to expect the same behavior (same level of feature support) on iOS10 as provided by the latest version of iOS11.

Comment: It's not directly stated in their docs, but the difference between uiwebview and wkwebview seems to be more in the internal processes than in the way it renders CSS. As i understand, for a given device, both should produce the same content, but with different performances. If you have the latest Ionic version, it also uses `wkwebview` by default, as Apple recommends it instead of uiwebview now. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47252756/7393478) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41135171/7393478) strongly suggests what i'm saying.